# "Atom beautify" not working in Atom

Tags: php

First of all l'm Japanese and my English is sometimes weird.

My situation is excatly the same as found in this URL:
https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/2107

I mean the same situation as "musayazlik".

[image]

This is on Windows 10:
I installed "php-cs-fixer" and of course "[Atom beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify)".

No error messages and not working.

There are no solutions?

I put "c:\xampp\php" to executable ▶︎PHP

and

put "c:\xampp\php-cs-fixer" to executable ▶︎PHP-CS-Fixer

I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the right paths to the file execs. 
You are missing the **\PHP\** folder.

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

and

```
C:\xampp\php\php-cs-fixer(full name of file).phar
```